# Open database in Visual Studio (Windows Mobile)

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, sqlite, windows-mobile

I try to open a database with Visual Studio 2008 but I have a error: no such table.

I created database with SQLiteAdmin and I added to project (View -> Server Explorer -> Data Connections -> Add -> SQLiteDatabaseSource)

Moreover, this database (myDatabase.sqlite) is in the folder of the project and the query: "SELECT Descripcion FROM Productos" in a SQLiteAdmin is OK.

I tried to change the path of Data Source but the error continues.

Sorry for my english. Thanks!!!

```
   string myConnString = "Data Source = myDatabase.sqlite";
   string mySelectQuery = "SELECT Descripcion FROM Productos";
   SQLiteConnection sqConnection = new SQLiteConnection(myConnString);
   SQLiteCommand sqCommand = new SQLiteCommand(mySelectQuery, sqConnection);
   sqConnection.Open();

   try
   {
       SQLiteDataReader sqReader = sqCommand.ExecuteReader(); //ERROR in run ###

       while (sqReader.Read())
       {
            Console.WriteLine(sqReader.GetInt32(0) + ", " + sqReader.GetString(sqReader.GetOrdinal("Descripcion")));
       }

            sqReader.Close();

    }

    finally
    {
            sqConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you have to select database? Try `USE databaseName;` before that query.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string needs to be the path to your database.

```
private const string fmtConnStr = @"Data Source=\\AppFolder\\data.db;Version=3;";
```